# Can't cache dynamic content with Squid

Tags: squid

I am trying to use squid in order to cache some dynamic content. The content comes from requests such as `/path/{id}`, where `id` is the identifier of the resource.
I have tried playing with the configuration file of squid but I had no success so far.

It can cache content like "/path/resource", but it does not work for the dynamic one.
The `access.log` is filled with `TCP_MISS_ABORTED`.

Here is my config file:

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl dynamic_content urlpath_regex ^/long_text/get/[0-9]+

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# This default configuration only allows localhost requests because a more
# permissive Squid installation could introduce new attack vectors into the
# network by proxying external TCP connections to unprotected services.
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow dynamic_content

# Protect web applications running on the same server as Squid. They often
# assume that only local users can access them at "localhost" ports.
http_access allow to_localhost
http_access allow all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
cache_mem 1000 MB
maximum_object_size 4 MB
#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

debug_options ALL,1 33,2
```

Also, for testing reasons, the squid service is running on the same server as both the client that is make the requests as well as the web server.

Edit: The objects are no larger than 1.5 MB

Edit2:The access logs look like this:

```
1707899048.785      6 192.168.100.150 TCP_MISS/200 12592 GET http://192.168.100.150:8080/long_text/get/113 - HIER_DIRECT/192.168.100.150 text/plain
1707899048.793      7 192.168.100.150 TCP_MISS_ABORTED/200 8488 GET http://192.168.100.150:8080/long_text/get/1868 - HIER_DIRECT/192.168.100.150 text/plain
1707899048.806     11 192.168.100.150 TCP_MISS_ABORTED/200 20800 GET http://192.168.100.150:8080/long_text/get/743 - HIER_DIRECT/192.168.100.150 text/plain
1707899048.814      8 192.168.100.150 TCP_MISS_ABORTED/200 20800 GET http://192.168.100.150:8080/long_text/get/1 - HIER_DIRECT/192.168.100.150 text/plain
1707899048.821      5 192.168.100.150 TCP_MISS_ABORTED/200 8488 GET http://192.168.100.150:8080/long_text/get/1412 - HIER_DIRECT/192.168.100.150 text/plain
1707899048.828      6 192.168.100.150 TCP_MISS_ABORTED/200 12592 GET http://192.168.100.150:8080/long_text/get/566 - HIER_DIRECT/192.168.100.150 text/plain
```

The majority of them are `TCP_MISS_ABORTED`, I would say that only one in a few hundreds are `TCP_MISS`, but I get no `TCP_MEM_HIT`.

Edit: Complete headers sent as a reponse by the web server:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=60
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 14 Feb 2024 09:25:32 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Edit: logs for consecutivly getting the same resource:

```
1707902670.872     18 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1045060 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/long_text/get/1 - HIER_DIRECT/127.0.0.1 text/plain
1707904558.006     12 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1045060 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/long_text/get/1 - HIER_DIRECT/127.0.0.1 text/plain
1707904558.777     11 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1045060 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/long_text/get/1 - HIER_DIRECT/127.0.0.1 text/plain
1707904559.535     15 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1045060 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/long_text/get/1 - HIER_DIRECT/127.0.0.1 text/plain
1707904560.233     11 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1045060 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/long_text/get/1 - HIER_DIRECT/127.0.0.1 text/plain
```

Comment: What are the `Cache-Control` headers for your objects?

Comment: Is the content cacheable?

Comment: Also, what is the number in `TCP_MISS_ABORTED/???`.

Comment: @symcbean @AlexD I set the headers as `Cache-Control: max-age=60`. It worked for non-dynamic content without specifing that it is public.

Comment: Whats the complete headers sent?

Comment: @AlexD I updated the post with a few logs copied from the `access.log` file, but they are 200 all

Comment: do you use it as a forward or backward proxy? Can you show us the webserver config please also

Comment: @vidarlo I updated the post again with the headers, but just the Cache-Control, Date, Content-Type and Transfer-Encoding ones

Comment: @djdomi honestly I don't know, I installed `squid` with `apt-get` and used the default config (slightly modified) that I got from squid. And the webserver doesn't have any particular config, I build a test one with the `net/http` library that golang provides, basically just the example provided by them.

Comment: okay, i think were gonna solve at the moment a [x-y-problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem)  what do you want to do, and what is the origin? - if you want to cache requests, that has come from a destination, then nginx would be easier, as it has already the builtin ability to cache requests from other hosts. Please Update the question

Comment: The log files you've shown us don't demonstrate the issue - the 6 URLs are all different. I suggest you confirm the gehaviour by retrieving the same URL consecutively a few times within a 60 second window.

Comment: @djdomi All I want is to use squid to cache requested data hosted on my personal machine (for testing reasons). All the data will have a path like "/path/get/{id}", where {id} is the identifier of the resource. That's all that I want. I also don't want to use nginx, I really want to make squid work.

Comment: @symcbean You are right and I am sorry, I've run now a request to get the same resource a few times and it results in all "TCP_MISS/200". I updated the question with new logs

Comment: i am sorry but home and enduser questions are offtopic, you want to look into an reverse proxy and nginx in example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `cache_mem`. It doesn't store objects larger than `maximum_object_size_in_memory` with the default value of 512 KB.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was indeed the problem. I was specifying the maximum object size of in-memory cache wrongly.

Comment: you can also force more behavior with https://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/refresh_pattern/